# Is it allowed to model only certain parts of a character in animation?

Tags: modeling, animation, shortcut

I am working on a short animated film (scenario & storyboarding phase). I think designing the main character will already take a significant part of my time. The main character's mother is never fully seen, only her hands are.

In this case, is it necessary to make a complete 3D model of her, or can I allow myself to model only the body parts appearing in the frame?
If I'm ever presenting this film, would it look lazy to have modeled parts only?

Comment: no of course you can only model the part that will appear on screen

Comment: Check out the [blend files of Blender's splash screen](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/). The girl of the *Junk Shop* (2.81) for example has no pelvis and no legs! Do not tell anyone! ;-)

Comment: Blender police will arrest you on the spot! 
Seriously though, whatever works for you, just do it, realistic or not, end result counts.

Comment: If you put work into parts that would **definitely never** appear in shot for a commercial studio, that would, at least, leave you open you to ridicule :D. Waste of time and money. Have a think, though, about shadows, reflections, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is, in fact, routine practice to model *only* that which appears on the screen.  How routine?  There's a famous scene of Harold Lloyd in the 1923 film *Safety Last* where he is hanging from a clock high about a city street.

[image: Harold Lloyd hanging from a clock in Safety Last]

[Or is he?](https://silentlocations.com/2012/02/29/how-harold-lloyd-filmed-safety-last/)

The point of set design in the movies for nearly 150 years has been to create the *illusion* of things that aren't present.

It's one of the rules of good set design that if it isn't there, then don't model it.

That rule applies to everything in a movie, not just the sets, even an animated movie, and even the characters in the movies.